# Getting a null pointer even though the hashmap value exists and the array exists as well?

Tags: java

I am doing this for a Codeforces question. The entry I am testing is as follows:
5 2 (new line)
1 3 1 4 2

The question for those curious is https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/450/A

Anyways, I am currently trying to manipulate a hashmap and rearrange entries but I am getting a null pointer for the line (indicate below): int num = fullInfo.get(i)[0];

I don't quite understand why because I have tested the statement and the hashmap does contain the appropriate array and the array is not empty either, so there should be no reason I am getting a null pointer.

Note: I apologize, I have an extra hashmap there labelled as info but I am not using it for anything so please pay no heed to that.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String[]line = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);

        String [] secondLine = br.readLine().split(" ");
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> info = new HashMap<>();

        HashMap<Integer, Integer[]> fullInfo = new HashMap <>();

        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
            info.put(i, Integer.parseInt(secondLine[i])); 
            Integer [] array = {Integer.parseInt(secondLine[i]), i};
            fullInfo.put(i, array);
        }

        int i = 0;
        int amt = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);

        while(fullInfo.size() > 1){
            int num = fullInfo.get(i)[0]; //null pointer here
            if(num <= amt){
                fullInfo.remove(i);

            }
            else {
                int lastKey = fullInfo.size()-1;
                int currentVal = fullInfo.get(i)[0]-amt;
                int ogIndex = fullInfo.get(i)[1];
                Integer [] curr = {currentVal, ogIndex};

                int lastVal = fullInfo.get(lastKey)[0];
                int lastIndexOG = fullInfo.get(lastKey)[1];
                Integer [] last = {lastVal, lastIndexOG};
                fullInfo.put(i, last);
                fullInfo.put(lastKey, curr);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(fullInfo);

    }
}
```

Comment: variable `i` is never changed.
You should try to debug first, before asking such questions.

Comment: Add `i++` after your last `else` block.  I added `System.out.println(i); System.out.println(fullInfo);` at the beginning of your `while` block to see the problem.  This is not a good place to debug null pointer exceptions, try https://coderanch.com/c/java.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I will keep that in mind next time I.G. and John Meyer!